# Calcule of $\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_{nm}}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty{a_{nm}}.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let  for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$  $$a_{nm}= \left\{ \begin{array}{rc}
1, & n=m\\ -1, & m=n+1 \\ 0, & \text{in other case} \end{array} \right.$$

Calcule:

1) $\,\,\,\,\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_{nm}}$.

2) $\,\,\,\,\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty{a_{nm}}.$

Intiutively I think that both sums are zero, but I don't can't to write this decently...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets do part $1$ "formally":

If $m=1$, and study $n=1,2,\cdots$, the only non-zero value is at $n=1$ where $a_{nm}=1$.

For any other fixed $m>1$, if we run through the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{nm}$, exactly two values of $n$ will have non-zero values, namely, $n=m-1$ and $n=m$ with values $-1$ and $1$ respectively so they cancel each other yielding a contribution of $0$.

So all these sums are $0$. Thus $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{nm}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n1} + \sum_{m=2}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{nm}=1+0=1$$

Now try doing the other part by yourself.

Comment: @Ravi...The sum in two also is 1 right?

Comment: @Ravi.sorry the first sum is 1...the second is 0 or 1?

Comment: Maybe you can actually try doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Let $s_m:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{nm}$ and observe that $s_1=1$ and $s_m=0$ for $m>1$

That tells us that:  $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{nm}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}s_m=1+0+0+0+\cdots=1$$

On base of that conclude that $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{nm}=1$$

Let $t_n:=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{nm}$ and observe that $t_n=0$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

That tells us that:  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{nm}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}t_n=0+0+0+0+\cdots=0$$